# How can I access the Java primitive int type in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to pass `int` parameters to the [BufferedImage.getSubImage()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) java method:

In groovy, I have the following code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 192;
int width = 288;
int height = 288;
bufferedImage.getSubImage(x, y, width, height)
```

In the snippet above, what is getting passed to `getSubImage()` seems to be a `java.lang.Integer`, not the primitive type. Therefore I'm getting the following error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubImage() is applicable for argument
>   types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.Integer) values: [0, 192, 288, 288]

In the groovy [documentation,](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_primitives_and_wrappers) it looks like groovy is purposely wrapping primitives as objects which leads to my question, **how can I pass a primitive type to a java method?**

Comment: I'd say, you misspelled the method name. should be `getSubimage()` instead of `getSubImage()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, you misspelled the method name. It should be `getSubimage()` instead of `getSubImage()`.